# Is "one-sided conversation" an oxymoron?

Tags: meaning, oxymoron

A conversation is thought to be between 2 or more people, who both talk (loose definition). If only one person spoke, did a conversation take place?

Answer (score 1):

A "one sided conversation" does not have to only have one participant. A conversation is "one-sided" if one person does *most* of the talking, with the other only making occasional small contributions, but it is still a conversation.

Similarly a game is "one-sided" if one participant is dominant over the other, but it is still a game.

Comment: What about in the case where only one person does talk. Does it not qualify as a conversation anymore?

Comment: If only one person contributes I would probably call it a monologue or something similar. However if the other person responded in a non-verbal way it might still be a conversation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sarcastic term.  What it expresses is that supposedly there was going to be a conversation, but then one person yakked, lectured or harangued, without letting the other person get a word in edgewise, and then it wasn't a conversation any more.  (It was a monologue.)